# Disable "Detached"-Action in SWT - "Wrong parent"-Exception

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

Im working in a project, with a Eclipse SWT-Application. On the tabs of all views there are the default-actions, for example the "Detached"-Action that takes the tab and creates a detached window for it.
In our case, this leads to the following exception:

```
    Widget has the wrong parent
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Widget has the wrong parent
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4064)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3998)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3969)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setMenu(Control.java:3159)
    at OUR-APPLICATION - Table
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.showMenu(Widget.java:1463)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.wmContextMenu(Widget.java:1559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5617)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4886)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProcW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.CallWindowProc(OS.java:2362)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.callWindowProc(Table.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table.windowProc(Table.java:5691)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessageW(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DispatchMessage(OS.java:2459)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3655)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at OUR-APPLICATION.run(Application.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at OUR-APPLICATION.Application.start(Application.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
```

I know that there is a constant called `ENABLE_DETACHED_VIEWS`in `IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants` and that the default value of which is true.

I now try to disable the "Detached"-Action in general (also hints how to disable it in one view would be appreciated). Is there a way I can override the default-value of said constant, or any other way of removing the "Detached"-action from the rightclick menu on my tabs?

Thanks for your help

EDIT:
We're working with SWT **3.6**

Comment: A more complete version of the stack trace might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it out myself. As far as I found out you have to extend `WorkbenchAdvisor`. 
In this subclass you have to override `createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor` in which you can override the `IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants` like this:

```
@Override
    public WorkbenchWindowAdvisor createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) {
        PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(IWorkbenchPreferenceConstants.ENABLE_DETACHED_VIEWS, false);
        return new ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(configurer);
    }
```

This will prevent the application from detaching any views and also remove the right-click action "Detached".

Be aware that (from what I found out) this solution will only work in version 3.X

Comment: How can that be a solution? You simply disable a prominent eclipse functionality because your code is not working